# postgresql - Mac Address Regex

Tags: greenplum

I am trying to retrieve all rows with correct mac address using the following query in Greenplum but I also get some rows with junk data like ??:??:??:??:??:??.When I pass the column to another function I get an error

> ERROR:  "?" is not a valid hexadecimal digit

Here is my select query

```
select * from table where mac_address like '%:%:%:%:%:%' 
                    and (length(mac_address)) = 17 
                    and mac_address like '^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$'
```

How can I filter out incorrect mac_addresses from a column in Greenplum?

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions

Comment: Thanks,your suggestion led me to finding ~ operator.

Comment: Why are you storing that in a varchar column and not a `macaddr`?

Comment: I am not , I don't work on the data warehouse team.Whoever created the table specified the schema.I just access the table.Apparently there is some junk in that column that doesn't conform to mac address format and they are now cleaning it.

Comment: Can't you cast the column to a mac address type, and then use the search functionality built into this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself, `mac_address ~ '^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$'`

```
select * from table where mac_address like '%:%:%:%:%:%' 
                    AND (length(mac_address)) = 17 
                    AND mac_address ~ '^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$'
limit 100;
```